# how to install python 3.6.9 on centos when it is on a workspace?

Tags: installation, python, centos, make

I am trying to install python 3.6.9 on centos. Here is what I do:

```
1. tar -xvf Python-3.6.9.tar
2. cd Python-3.6.9
3. ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.6 --enable-optimizations
4. make
5. make install
```

when I finish make, I have got:
[image]

When I try make install:
[image]

Then, based on some online advice, I try to do 
[image]

But it just cannot connect at all.

Then, I try to download the zlib from https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/zlib-devel-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64.rpm.html to my local computer, and then install it. But I have got:
[image]

Could anyone please help me out here: how to install python on centos?

Comment: With the command `yum install python36` in centos, it shows python version 3.6. Do you want any different configuration?

Comment: Thanks. But I do not really understand you. Could you be more specific? Also, I just want to install python 3.6 or higher, and pycharm. So I can use them. I do not have any more request

Comment: I mean `yum install python36` command can install that why not you choose it?

Comment: I am doing this on a workspace. The internet usage is restricted. I have tried. It cannot link to any mirror. All connection timed out